# rails 3+ authentication for just one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, authentication

like in title - is there any solution for authentication for just one user - e.g. to secure personal website? or I should delete registration form and make one user by myself in rails console?

Answer (score 3):

This is easy and straightforward:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

Using the db would seem like overkill for one user, but if you want to use the DB, there is also a screencast for that:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast

Note that the password salt mentioned in the cast is not necessary with current versions of BCrypt but it won't hurt anything to leave it in.

Comment: I prefer to create the user data in database, but thanks - I can use that solution + using db ;)